# Matching collection items by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**Relations between two mongo collections.**

I have 2 collections: Entries and Labels:

```
// example Entry
{
  "_id": "4ZCBv5ogLStfFxpvp",
  "title": "Some other title",
  "entryLabels": [
    "TFrYvEujpqbMryWEZ",
    "rn8Z57NsEYse7nYTo",
    "rn8Z57NsEYse73YTo"
  ],
  "author": "TMviRL8otm3ZsddSt",
  "createdAt": "2016-01-16T15:21:43.153Z",
  "date": "2016-01-16T15:21:43.153Z"
}

// Example Label
{
  "_id": "9NCNPGH8F5MWNzjkA",
  "color": "#333",
  "name": "Grey Label",
  "author": "TMviRL8otm3ZsddSt"
}
```

As it's possible to have multiple labels to an Entry, I keep the Label IDs in that entryLabels field.
My plan was to save only the label ids and then query the Labels collection based on that.

This is ok if I have a single labelID because I can query the Labels collection based on that ID and return a label. However I have an array of IDs and I have to return multiple Labels.

My attempt is like this(in the template helper) :

```
labels: function(event){
    var entryLabels = this.entryLabels;

    var arr = []
    for(i = 0; i < entryLabels.length; i++) {
        var label = entryLabels[i];
        var theLabel = Labels.find({_id: entryLabels[i]}).fetch();

        arr.push(theLabel);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

then, in the template:

```
{{#each labels}}
    {{name}}
    <p>asd</p>
{{/each}}
```

---

This returns 'asd' 3 times but I cannot access the label properties like name

So, I guess my question is, how can I access those properties.
Also.. am I doing this the right way?

Comment: (I really missed the `fetch()` detail, sorry again!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I doing this the right way?

I would say no. With mongo like almost any other database, you can retrieve multiple documents at a time. Why fetch one at a time in a `for-loop` when you can do

```
labels: function(event){
    var entryLabels = this.entryLabels;
    var arr = Labels.find({_id: {$in: entryLabels}}).fetch();
    return arr;
}
```

This will also fix your "I cannot access the label properties like name" problem, because your old `arr` was an **array** of **array** of **documents**, not an array of documents as you expected.

Comment: @charliebrownie  - it will return an array and not run async because of `fetch`. Almost exact same example in the documentation http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find

Comment: (I really missed the `fetch()` detail, sorry again!!)

Answer (score 0):

Judicious duplication of data can be part of creating optimal document database schemas.  That having been said, Martin's Answer should be good.  `Labels.find().fetch()` are Meteor methods on the Meteor Mongo Labels collection, not an async MongoDb find on the Mongo Labels Collection.